# Store _Id as object or string in MongoDB?

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and MongoDB.
In this system I am saving the full name and _ID of users that the selected user
is following.

What is best to do regarding the _Id? Store it as an object or as a string?
If I store it as an object I need to convert it to string when echoing out followers otherwise
the output looks strange.

My question is really. Is it ok to store the _Id as a string rather than an object?
What is the downside of storing as string?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Performance for requests (and updates) are really better with objectid. More over, objectid are quite small in space.

From the official doc :

> BSON includes a binary data datatype for storing byte arrays. Using
>   this will make the id values, and their respective keys in the _id
>   index, twice as small.

here are 2 links that can help you : 
- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Object+IDs
- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Answer (score 2):

When you use `ObjectId`, it generates `_id` as a unique value in all your computers. So if you use Sharding, you will not worry about you `_id` conflicts. See how ObjectId generates in [specification](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification)

But if you use string, you should generate it carefully.