# Mongodb collection _id

Tags: performance, mongodb, collections

By default `_id` field is generated as `new ObjectId()`, which has 96 bits (12 bytes).

Does `_id` size affect collection performance? What if I'll use 128 bits (160 bits or 256 bits) strings instead of native `ObjectId`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store \_Id as object or string in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764781/store-id-as-object-or-string-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2):

In query performance, it is unlikely to matter. The index on _id is a sorted index implemented as a binary tree, so the actual length of the values doesn't matter much.

Using a longer string as _id will of course make your documents larger. Larger documents mean that less documents will be cached in RAM which will result in worse performance for larger databases. But when that string is a part of the documents anyway, using them as _id would save space because you won't need an additonal _id anymore.

Answer (score 1):

By default `_id` filed is indexed(primary key) and if you tend to use a custom value set for it(say String) factually it will just consume more space. It will not have any significant impact on your query performance. Index size hardly contributes to query performance. You can verify this with sample code.