# Is it better to save id of a document in another document as ObjectId or String

Tags: mongodb

Lets take a simple "bad" example : lets assume I have 2 collections 'person' and 'address'. And lets assume in 'address' I want to store '_id' of the person the address is associated with. Is there any benefit to store this "referential key" item as ObjectId vs string in 'address' collection?

I feel like storing them as string should not hurt but I have not worked in mongo for very long and do not know if it will hurt down the road if I follow this pattern.

I read the post here : [Store _Id as object or string in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764781/store-id-as-object-or-string-in-mongodb)
And its said that ObjectId is faster, and I assume its true if you are fetching/updating using the ObjectId in parent collection(for eg. fetching/updating 'person' collection using person._id as ObjectId), but I couldn't find anything that suggests that same could be true if searching by string id representation in other collection(in our example search in address collection by person._id as string)

Your feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: How is this a different question? An ObjectId is stored in 12-bytes. A string with the hexadecimal charcters of an ObjectId is 24-bytes ( just for characters, the plus trailing then plus size reference). More space, more time. Slower! That should not be difficult to work out.

Comment: You are right, was trying to work things out with ember data and didnt see much point in converting objectid to string and back to objectId and i was searching for convenience more than performance. This morning i did a search and this question has been asked in other form too.

Comment: For the record the answer you accepted here makes the other important point. You cannot match things together on different "types" without manually re-casting to either string or ObjectId values. Personally I really prefer all external API to use the extended JSON form `{ "_id": { "$oid": "56ea9e8bb1e015d13b376db5" } }` since if my client can actually deserialize back to an `ObjectId` then I let it know that is what the data actually is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regardless of performance, you should store the "referential key" in the same format as the _id field that you are referring too. That means that if your referred document is:

```
{ _id: ObjectID("68746287..."), value: 'foo' }
```

then you'd refer to it as:

```
{ _id: ObjectID(…parent document id…), subDoc: ObjectID("68746287...")
```

If the document that you're pointing to has a string as an ID, then it'd look like:

```
{ _id: "derick-address-1", value: 'foo' }
```

then you'd refer to it as:

```
{ _id: ObjectID(…parent document id…), subDoc: "derick-address-1" }
```

Besides that, because you're talking about persons and addresses, it might make more sense to *not* have them in two documents altogether, but instead embed the document:

```
{ _id: ObjectID(…parent document id…),
  'name' : 'Derick',
  'addresses' : [
     { 'type' : 'Home', 'street' : 'Victoria Road' },
     { 'type' : 'Work', 'street' : 'King William Street' },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As for use `string` as id of document, in [`meteor collection`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection), you could generate the document id either `Random.id()` as string or `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()` as `ObjectId`.

In this discussion loop, [Mongodb string id vs ObjectId](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk/oQYZQxCAKN8J), here is one good summary,

> **ObjectId Pros**
>
> - it has an embedded timestamp in it.
> - it's the default Mongo _id type; ubiquitous
> - interoperability with other apps and drivers

> **ObjectId Cons**
>
> - it's an object, and a little more difficult to manipulate in practice.
> - there will be times when you forget to wrap your string in new ObjectId()
> - it requires server side object creation to maintain _id uniqueness
>   - which makes generating them client-side by minimongo problematic

> **String Pros**
>
> - developers can create domain specific _id topologies

> **String Cons**
>
> - developer has to ensure uniqueness of _ids
> - findAndModify() and getNextSequence() queries may be invalidated

All those information above is based on the `meteor` framework. For Mongodb, it is better to use `ObjectId`, reasons are in the question linked in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Storing it as objectId is benificial. It is faster as ObjectId size is 12 bytes compared to string which takes 24 bytes.

Also, You should try to de-normalize your collections so that you don't need to make 2 collections (Opposite to RDBMS).

Something like this might be better in general:

```
{ _id : "1",
  person : { 
             Name : "abc",
             age: 20
           },
  address : { 
             street : "1st main",
             city: "Bangalore",
             country: "India"
            }
}
```

But again, it depends on your use case. This might be not suitable sometimes.

Hope that helps! :)