# Performance gains to using UUID instead of its string representation as _id on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, performance, key, uuid

In REST applications, I need to convert `UUID` string representation (received in `json`) to `UUID Object` to store it on MongoDB's `_id` field. I'm doing that as I heard there is a performance gain in the lookup/insertion time when using `UUID` vs `String`.

Is there really a performance gain when using `UUID` as `_id` on MongoDB instead of its string representation? (even small performance gains can have a big impact for me)

PS: I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764781/store-id-as-object-or-string-in-mongodb) that says performance is better for `ObjectID` (not exactly the same, not sure it applies to `UUID`), but the only reason seems to be the potential smaller size of `ObjectID` vs `String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using `PyMongo` which encode `UUID` as a `BSON::Binary`.

We can see from the [MongoDB doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) that:

> For a more efficient storage of the UUID values in the collection and
>   in the _id index, store the UUID as a value of the BSON BinData type.
>   Index keys that are of the BinData type are more efficiently stored in
>   the index if: the binary subtype value is in the range of 0-7 or
>   128-135, and the length of the byte array is: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
>   8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 24, or 32.

My `UUID` is in that range, so the performance will be increased over the `String` representation.

Comment: It appears that you more or less answered your own question. :-) It's worth emphasizing that storing as UUID will save significant space in the database. Your index size will be reduced by nearly half when storing as BinData vs String, and the document size will also be reduced. This means that you will be able to keep more index data and more document data in memory (cache), and save space on disk.